# Reading Application Configuration File - .NET 4

Tags: c#

What is the preferred way of reading an application's configuration file in .NET 4? I've seen several articles on how to do with .NET 2. I don't know if things have changed/improved with .NET 4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ConfigurationManager is still the preferred way of reading the application config and web config files.

To use it you will first need to add a reference in your project to System.Configuration.

Then you will need to add a reference to it in your class with:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Once you have done this you will be able to access things like your AppSettings and ConnectionStrings by calling these static properties on the ConfigurationManager class.

e.g.

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["settingname"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Most developers seem to be happy with the string-based `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` style of configuration, but there is another way: *strongly typed configuration*.

The MSDN reference is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx

In a nutshell, you can define your own configuration setting section and have your own strongly typed configuration items in there. Amongst other things this

- (as the name implies) can force use of enumerated options
- allows you to define user-based or application-based settings
- allows you to define defaults

The main downside is that it's a bit of a faff to get going as there's quite a bit of code to implement and test.